# google-cloud-sdk install ERROR: (gcloud.components.update) The provided path must exist

Tags: macos, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sdk

I have tried installing google-cloud-sdk on a mac OS 10 via the command line and homebrew and I get the same error.

**ERROR: (gcloud.components.update) The provided path must exist.**

I don't understand how the path could be missing if I am downloading a zipped file, extracting it and running the install script. What more can I do to get the install to work?

I have tried various work-arounds. I have upgraded homebrew. Used various sudo commands. And I still get the same error.

Output from homebrew install below:

```
○ → brew install --cask google-cloud-sdk
Updating Homebrew...
==> Auto-updated Homebrew!
Updated 2 taps (homebrew/core and homebrew/cask).
==> New Formulae
gnupg@2.2
==> Updated Formulae
Updated 1 formula.
==> Updated Casks
Updated 13 casks.

==> Caveats
google-cloud-sdk is installed at /usr/local/Caskroom/google-cloud-sdk/latest/google-cloud-sdk. Add your profile:

  for bash users
    source "/usr/local/Caskroom/google-cloud-sdk/latest/google-cloud-sdk/path.bash.inc"
    source "/usr/local/Caskroom/google-cloud-sdk/latest/google-cloud-sdk/completion.bash.inc"

  for zsh users
    source "/usr/local/Caskroom/google-cloud-sdk/latest/google-cloud-sdk/path.zsh.inc"
    source "/usr/local/Caskroom/google-cloud-sdk/latest/google-cloud-sdk/completion.zsh.inc"

  for fish users
    source "/usr/local/Caskroom/google-cloud-sdk/latest/google-cloud-sdk/path.fish.inc"

==> Downloading https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/release/google-cloud-sdk.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Users/wxc3426/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/cda39f18c3069c1a4ac0cd5b1d91541af945cd331eba8443c58ec5c890343c0a--google-cloud-sdk.tar.gz
Warning: No checksum defined for cask 'google-cloud-sdk', skipping verification.
All formula dependencies satisfied.
==> Installing Cask google-cloud-sdk
Beginning update. This process may take several minutes.
ERROR: (gcloud.components.update) The provided path must exist.
==> Purging files for version latest of Cask google-cloud-sdk
Error: Failure while executing; `/usr/bin/env CLOUDSDK_PYTHON=/usr/local/opt/python@3.9/bin/python3 /usr/local/Caskroom/google-cloud-sdk/latest/google-cloud-sdk/install.sh --usage-reporting false --bash-completion false --path-update false --rc-path false --quiet` exited with 1. Here's the output:
Welcome to the Google Cloud SDK!
Beginning update. This process may take several minutes.
ERROR: (gcloud.components.update) The provided path must exist.

This will install all the core command line tools necessary for working with
the Google Cloud Platform.
```

Comment: Could you try following this [link](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/quickstart#mac)? May I know if you're able to finish until Step 2c without errors? If you got a permission error, it is very likely that `~/.config/gcloud` is only accessible by root. After running the command, please let me know of the output.

Comment: This is the result of the running Step 2c:
○ → ./google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud init
Checking network connection...done.
ERROR: Reachability Check failed.
    Cannot reach https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/channels/rapid/components-2.json with httplib2 (SSLCertVerificationError)
    Cannot reach https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/channels/rapid/components-2.json with requests (SSLError)
Network connection problems may be due to proxy or firewall settings.

Comment: I got my error fixed.
Searched for the error above. 
Found this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65208575/google-cloud-sdk-throws-reachability-check-failed-error
Followed the instructions in the top rated answer given by John Hanley
Basically uninstalled all versions of Python. ( https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/5880/python/uninstall )
Cleaned up homebrew.
Re-ran ~/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud init
Got the same errors but this time it offered me the option to continue and sent me to a google login page.
Logged in.
Completed successfully.

Comment: That's great to know. Please post it as an answer. This way others can upvote your solution

Answer (score 1):

I got my error fixed.
Searched for the error above.

Found this question stackoverflow.com/questions/65208575/…

Followed the instructions in the top rated answer given by John Hanley

Basically uninstalled all versions of Python. ( macupdate.com/app/mac/5880/python/uninstall )
Cleaned up homebrew.
Re-ran ~/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud init
Got the same errors but this time it offered me the option to continue and sent me to a google login page.
Logged in.
Completed successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the steps that wooper and Dondi posted, here could be a possible answer:

Follow [these](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/quickstart#mac) steps at least until 2c, and if a permission error is shown, is very likely that `~/.config/gcloud` is only accessible by root.

If after running `./google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud init` you get the following error:

> ERROR: Reachability Check failed. Cannot reach
> dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/channels/rapid/components-2.json with
> httplib2 (SSLCertVerificationError) Cannot reach
> dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/channels/rapid/components-2.json with
> requests (SSLError) Network connection problems may be due to proxy or
> firewall settings.

You may want to check the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65209385/15747954) from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65208575/google-cloud-sdk-throws-reachability-check-failed-error) to uninstall all versions of Python and clean up homebrew.

This should let you log in via Google login page.

Answer (score 0):

I found some env variable (such as cert) is set that is invalid.

1. download google cloud sdk
2. unzip and go to /bin directory
3. gcloud config list

Observe any env variable that is based on path and is incorrectly set.
From there, you can ./gcloud config set {env} {correct_value} or reconfigure env from scratch