# Google Cloud: ERROR: Reachability Check failed

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-sdk

I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65209385/10672994) already. But it didn't help, also, I re-installed gcloud CLI, but now I am not able to install CLI anymore because of the following error.

Here is my output for  `./google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud init`

```
ERROR: Reachability Check failed.
    Cannot reach https://cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects with httplib2 (SSLCertVerificationError)
    Cannot reach https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform with httplib2 (SSLCertVerificationError)
    Cannot reach https://cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects with requests (SSLError)
    Cannot reach https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform with requests (SSLError)
Network connection problems may be due to proxy or firewall settings.
```

Also, I am not behind any corporate proxy.

It was working perfectly few days ago, until today.I did not changed any settings whatsoever, I didn't install any new services whatsoever.
Output for `./google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud info`.

```
./google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud info
Google Cloud SDK [354.0.0]


Python Version: [3.7.9 (v3.7.9:13c94747c7, Aug 15 2020, 01:31:08)  [Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)]]
Python Location: [/Users/myname/.config/gcloud/virtenv/bin/python3]
Site Packages: [Enabled]

Installation Root: [/Users/myname/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk]
Installed Components:
  gsutil: [4.67]
  core: [2021.08.20]
  bq: [2.0.71]
System PATH: [/Users/myname/.config/gcloud/virtenv/bin:/Users/myname/Downloads/apache-maven-3.8.4/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/go/bin:/usr/local/munki:/usr/local/opt/go/libexec/bin:/Users/myname/go/bin]
Python PATH: [/Users/myname/Downloads/./google-cloud-sdk/lib/third_party:/Users/myname/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/lib:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python37.zip:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload:/Users/myname/.config/gcloud/virtenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages]
Cloud SDK on PATH: [False]
Kubectl on PATH: [/usr/local/bin/kubectl]

Installation Properties: [/Users/myname/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/properties]
User Config Directory: [/Users/myname/.config/gcloud]
Active Configuration Name: [default]
Active Configuration Path: [/Users/myname/.config/gcloud/configurations/config_default]

Account: [None]
Project: [None]

Current Properties:
  [core]
    disable_usage_reporting: [True]

Logs Directory: [/Users/myname/.config/gcloud/logs]
Last Log File: [/Users/myname/.config/gcloud/logs/2022.08.10/15.35.06.807614.log]

git: [git version 2.32.0 (Apple Git-132)]
ssh: [OpenSSH_8.1p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3]
```

Comment: Is this issue present for other members of your organization? This is to know whether this is a general issue within your environment or an isolated issue within the exact workstation that you've been using so far to attempt to authenticate.

Comment: @Andrés this has been just an issue for me and  no one else in my team/org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update on this, just disable the ssl validation and everything will work.

`gcloud config set auth/disable_ssl_validation  True`